# Xamarin Android: What is the input and output for TFLite object detection?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to pull off an object detection. I am using `Xamarin Forms` and `Xamarin.Tensorflow.Lite`. First, I load my model:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.OpenFd("model.tflite");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor);
FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.Channel;
long startOffset = fileDescriptor.StartOffset;
long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.DeclaredLength;
var asd = fileChannel.Map(FileChannel.MapMode.ReadOnly, startOffset, declaredLength);
var model = new Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Interpreter(asd);
```

I know I should call `model.Run()`, but I don't quite know what parameters to give it. I want to give it an image and to read the data back? How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should read Image to the `bitmap`

`var bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(image.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage());`

Then Convert `bitmap` to `float[]` like following code.

```
      static float[] GetBitmapPixels(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var floatValues = new float[_inputSize * _inputSize * 3];

        using (var scaledBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, _inputSize, _inputSize, false))
        {
            using (var resizedBitmap = scaledBitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, false))
            {
                var intValues = new int[_inputSize * _inputSize];
                resizedBitmap.GetPixels(intValues, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height);

                for (int i = 0; i < intValues.Length; ++i)
                {
                    var val = intValues[i];

                    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((val & 0xFF) - 104);
                    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - 117);
                    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - 123);
                }

                resizedBitmap.Recycle();
            }

            scaledBitmap.Recycle();
        }

        return floatValues;
    }
```

In the end, we can read the data back.

```
      public string RecognizeImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var outputNames = new[] { OutputName };
        var floatValues = GetBitmapPixels(bitmap);
        var outputs = new float[labels.Count];

        inferenceInterface.Feed(InputName, floatValues, 1, _inputSize, _inputSize, 3);
        inferenceInterface.Run(outputNames);
        inferenceInterface.Fetch(OutputName, outputs);

        var results = new List<Tuple<float, string>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < outputs.Length; ++i)
            results.Add(Tuple.Create(outputs[i], labels[i]));

        return results.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item1).First().Item2;
    }
```

Here is a blog about it.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-apps-tensorflow/

And here is demo.
https://github.com/jimbobbennett/blog-samples/tree/master/UsingTensorFlowAndAzureInAndroid

Comment: Ok, but I am facing this error when calling TensorFlowInferenceInterface's constructor: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load model from 'model1.pb'.

Comment: I tried the demo's .pb file and it worked, but when I put my own file(I got it from Google's cloud platform) it is not working.

Comment: Did you set the build action of model.pb and labels.txt to the `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: Yes, they are set to AndroidAsset.

Comment: Based on your error, I search it, I found this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35707#issuecomment-573819277  , you will probably need to follow instructions for float models.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I got around this problem by transferring everything to the server-side of my application. Eventually, I wrote all the code that I need in Python, which is easier to use than Xamarin's Tensorflow implementation for this task.

Comment: The question was about object detection io, but this answer and referenced blog concern image classification, and so the inputs and outputs (mostly outputs) in the sample code are for image classification.

Answer (score 0):

I have had difficulty figuring out the outputs as well for object detection models (all the Microsoft blogs are about image classification models). The input and outputs for Tensorflow Lite are the same regardless of language (see [tf docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#output_signature)), but its difficult with all the casting that is required for doing it in a Xamarin app.

The output depends on your model of course, Essentially you want to use RunForMultipleInputsOutputs() and create an output object that is a map of arrays that match the output tensors. Input is the same as for image classification, but placed in an array.
Here is an [excerpt from a working app](https://github.com/h-maac/Xamarin.Android.TensorFlow.Lite/blob/master/TFLDemo/ObjectDetection/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.cs)

```cs
            outputLocations = CreateJagged(1, NUM_DETECTIONS, 4);
            outputClasses = CreateJagged(1, NUM_DETECTIONS);
            outputScores = CreateJagged(1, NUM_DETECTIONS);
            numDetections = new float[1];

            var mOutputLocations= OutputLocations;
            var mOutputClasses= OutputClasses;
            var mOutputScores= OutputScores;

            Java.Lang.Object[] inputArray = { imgData };

            var outputMap = new Dictionary<Java.Lang.Integer, Java.Lang.Object>();
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(0), mOutputLocations);
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(1), mOutputClasses);
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(2), mOutputScores);
            outputMap.Add(new Java.Lang.Integer(3), numDetections);
         
            tfLite.RunForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
```

Have a look at this GitHub Issue where I have more example code, and I got it to work with a tflite model exported from Azure Custom Vision: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/668
And I wrote a blog about implementing it all: https://intellitect.com/blog/object-detection-tensorflow-lite/